# Which one is the larger , $10^{30!}$ or $10^{30}!$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality

So, I have got this problem in which one is asked to find the greater one between $10^{30!}$ or $10^{30}!$.

Taking $\log$ both sides leads me nowhere.

Comment: $({}{}10^{30})!$

Comment: You may compare the max no. of digits of first one $10^{30!}$ with min. of digits in $10^{30}!$. Second one will be bigger as it will have more digits.

Comment: Put in Stirling's approximation and then take the log.

Comment: Interestingly $f(x)=10^{x!} $ and $g(x)=10^x!$ we have for $f(27)<g(27)$ but $f(28)>g(28)$ . Nice problem!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want Stirling's approximation here: $\ln n! \approx n \ln n - n$.   Here $\ln$ is the natural log.

So $\ln (10^{30})! \approx 10^{30} \ln 10^{30} - 10^{30}$.  Now $\ln 10^{30} = 30 \ln 10 < 30 \times 3 < 100$, and so  $\ln (10^{30})! < 10^{32}$.

On the other hand, $\ln 10^{30!} = 30! \ln 10$.  You can verify that $30! > 10^{32}$. and so $\ln 10^{30!} > 10^{32}$.

Thus $10^{30!}$ is the larger of the two.

Comment: I was wondering why nobody was [just 2x checking](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%5E(30!)>(10%5E(30))!)...

Comment: How far away from the origin is the approximation relatable though? Or is that not of significance here?

Comment: @MathAsFun: Imagine you are asked for solve this problem in an exam. What do you do? Wolfram is a good tool for check the answer but it isn't the answer. Of course this question doesn't worth for me, it is just curious and wolfram is enough but... For other people this question is important.

Comment: @Dog_69 You're missing the point of my comment, but it's unimportant. Best wishes!

Comment: @MathAsFun: Maybe. In this case sorry.

Comment: The "!" should be inside the parentheses at $\ln(10^{30})!$

Answer (score 1):

$x! < x^x\\
10^{30}! < (10^{30})^{10^{30}}$

While 
$10^{30!} = (10^{30})^{29!}$

Since $10^{30} > 1$, if $29! > 10^{30}$ (which it is) then $10^{30!} > 10^{30}!$

Comment: @hardmath  Really? I thought what I had was pretty easy to follow.

Comment: In my opinion the proof is clear. However, I would like to see a proof for the inequality $29!>10^{30}$, because it's not obvious. I mean, you are proving that $10^{30!}>10^{30}!$, so to do a fantastic answer you should prove the other because isn't obvious (at least for me).

Comment: @Dog_69: It's rather tight in that $10^{30} \lt 29! \lt 10^{31}$.

Comment: Using Pari/GP and the log- and lngamma-function I get a critical point between $27$ and $28$ (in place of $30$): `[log(10)*27!;lngamma(10^27)] --> [2.50725484761 E28; 6.11697975108 E28]` and 
`[log(10)*28!;lngamma(10^28)] --> [7.02031357331 E29; 6.34723826038 E29]`